# If $j_{1},...,j_{n}:V_{\lambda+1}\rightarrow V_{\lambda+1}$ are elementary embeddings, then does $j_{1}(A)=...=j_{n}(A)=A$ for some linear order $A$?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, large-cardinals

Suppose that $j_{1},\dots,j_{n}:V_{\lambda+1}\rightarrow V_{\lambda+1}$ are elementary embeddings. Then does there necessarily exist a linear ordering $A$ of $V_{\lambda}$ such that $j_{1}(A)=\dots=j_{n}(A)=A$? The result holds if $V_{\lambda}\models(V=HOD)$ which is consistent with the existence of an elementary embedding $j:V_{\lambda+1}\rightarrow V_{\lambda+1}$, but does the result hold in general without any additional hypotheses? I am also interested in the version of this question when $j_{1},\dots,j_{n}$ are only elementary embeddings from $V_{\lambda}$ to $V_{\lambda}$.

The case when $n=1$ is easy since if $j:V_{\lambda+1}\rightarrow V_{\lambda+1}$ is an elementary embedding and if $B$ is a linear ordering on $V_{\mathrm{crit}(j)}$, then $A=\bigcup_{n}j^{n}(B)$ is a linear ordering on $V_{\lambda}$ with $j(A)=A$. I am therefore looking at whether the result holds in general instead of particular instances of the result.

Comment: What about well-orders?

Comment: Can you answer the question even in the special case where there are only two embeddings, and they agree on the ordinals? I am tending to think we might make a counterexample, by producing embeddings that have fundamental disagreements, so that no linear order can be stretched in the same way by all of them.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins. Even for your special case, the possible obstruction to the existence of a linear ordering is when we have only two embeddings that agree on the ordinals is probably not a purely algebraic obstruction. My computations suggest that for every finite self-distributive algebra $X$ for which there is a coherent notion of a critical point, there is a linear ordering $\leq$ on $X$ such that $y\leq z$ implies $x*y\leq x*z$ and such linear orderings $\leq$ on $X$ arise from the linear orderings $A$ with $j(A)=A$.

Comment: Let me correct my original comments. Let $A$ be an alphabet with a linear ordering. Then $(A^{\leq 2^{n}})^{+}$ can be endowed with a unique self-distributive operation $*$ such that $x*a=xa$ whenever $|x|<2^{n},a\in A$ and $x*y=y$ whenever $|x|=2^{n}$. Let $\phi_{r}:(A^{\leq 2^{n}})^{+}\rightarrow(A^{\leq 2^{n}})^{+}$ be the unique homomorphism where $\phi_{r}(a)$ for $a\in A$. Then let $<^{L}$ be the ordering on $(A^{\leq 2^{n}})^{+}$ where we set $x<^{L}y$ if and only if there is some $r$ with $\phi_{s}(x)=\phi_{s}(y)$ for $s<r$ but where $\phi_{r}(x)<^{lex}\phi_{r}(y)$.

Comment: In the algebra, $(A^{\leq 2^{n}})^{n}$, we have $y\leq^{L}z$ implies $x*y\leq^{L}x*z$ (i.e. $\leq^{L}$ is compatible with $*$). The orderings $\leq^{L}$ on each $(A^{\leq 2^{n}})^{n}$ cohere to form a compatible linear ordering on the inverse limit $\varprojlim_{n}(A^{\leq 2^{n}})^{n}$ which contains a dense $G_{\delta}$ subset that resembles $\mathcal{E}_{\lambda}$. In particular, this $G_{\delta}$-subset is an algebraization of the the algebra of elementary embeddings generated by very distinct embeddings $(j_{a})_{a\in A}$ where $j_{a}|_{\lambda}=j_{b}|_{\lambda}$ for each $a,b\in A$.

Comment: I therefore conjecture that for a natural construction where one has two elementary embeddings that agree on the ordinals, then there is a linear ordering preserved by these embeddings.

Comment: My idea had nothing to do with the algebraic considerations. I am imagining making a counterexample by starting with a fixed embedding, and then performing forcing to lift it in two different manners.  The resulting embeddings would agree on the ground model and in particular on the ordinals. What I would expect from these lifts is that they stretch the new sets in fundamentally different ways, and that perhaps this might imply that any linear order on $V_{\kappa_0}$ will be stretched differently by them.

Comment: Joel. That seems like a good idea since in your scenario, we cannot preserve any well-ordering of order type $\lambda$. In an answer to Monroe Eskew's question, if $j,k$ are the elementary embeddings in Joel's scenario, and  $f:V_{\lambda}\rightarrow\lambda$ is the well ordering corresponding to $A$, then for each $x\in V_{\lambda}$, $f(j(x))=j(f(x))=k(f(x))=f(k(x))$ which implies that $j(x)=k(x)$, a contradiction.

Comment: I would be interested to see some more algebraic features on finite algebras that cannot arise from elementary embeddings. So far, I have seen many finite algebras where $\mathrm{crit}((x*x)*y)>\mathrm{crit}(x*y)$ while in set theory, the elementary embeddings must satisfy $(j*j)(\alpha)\leq j(\alpha)$. I don't know of any other good examples of when the algebraic features do not extend to large cardinals.